# How could I extract a substring from large text using in Notepad++ or C#

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I'd like to extract only the text between `'` mail adress `'`  between each substring..

**How to import only email address notepad++ macro or c# ?**

Sample.txt;

> (8428, 'John Doe', 'johndoe@testdomain.com', '05.Sep.2015 - 19:09:14', '12.222.100.100', 'sABqBpMRYh', '1', 0),
>
> (8429, 'Chris down', 'chrisdown@hotmail.com', '05.Sep.2015 -
>   19:10:03', '11.214.100.100', 'z0gWsvcOMO', '1', 1),

Help me please.

Regards

Comment: please also provide example input

Comment: Using String Split method around commas may be better.  input.Split(new char[] {','})

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what your input data looks like / what your output should look like. Additionally, without seeing any code you've started so far I don't know where to begin with a solution for you, but perhaps something like this will help.

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile).ToList<string>();
List<string> data = new List<string>();
List<int> allIndices = lines.Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .Where(x => x.Str.Contains("'"))
    .Select(x => x.Index).ToList<int>();

for (int j = 0; j < allIndices.Count() - 1; j++)
    data.AddRange(lines.GetRange(allIndices[j], (allIndices[j + 1] - allIndices[j])));
```

- `lines` will contain all the data from the file
- `data` is an empty list that will be added to
- `allIndices` is a list of every location where a `'` occurs.

The `for` loop iterates over `allIndices` getting all of the content from `lines` in between each `'` and adds that to `data`.

What you do with `data` after that is up to you.

Comment: Hello, I have got the mailaddress.txt ... With the substring "xxx@xxxx.xxx" sign we can have? To filter email?